# finding records between date ranges returns empty in codeigniter activerecord

Tags: codeigniter, date, activerecord

I have a table with a date column invoiceDate. In that there is a record with value of invoiceDate as 28-02-13

Now i use the below to fetch records between the date ranges:

```
            $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('salesinvoices');
    $dateone=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('26-02-13'));
    $datetwo=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('12-03-13'));
    $this->db->where('invoiceDate >=', $dateone);
    $this->db->where('invoiceDate <=', $datetwo);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $results = $query->result();
    print_r($results);
```

I always get a empty record :(

Comment: what is the type of your column date or datetime?

Answer (score 3):

I found the root of my issue. Strtotime sees dash as minus sign and peforms operation. I made it working using this:

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', '2026-02-13')));
```

So i replaced all dashes with / and it worked. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and the generated query was

```
SELECT * FROM "salesinvoices" 
WHERE "invoiceDate" >= '2026-02-13' 
AND "invoiceDate" <= '2012-03-13'
```

So it looks like the problem is in **strtotime**, which misinterprets the date.

Comment: Hey i made it work. See my answer below. Thanks for your help :)